# codeigniter : Cant display value from input text using $_POST to SQLcode inside model

Tags: php, codeigniter

the function sumqtyin() inside codeigniter model

```
function sumqtyin(){
    $kdbahan = $_POST['kode_bahan_baku']; //i wanna echo a value from the input text kode_bahan_baku but it always says error "undefined index kode_bahan_baku"
    $datenow = date("Y-m-d");
    return $this->db->query("
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(qty_in),0) AS qty_in 
        FROM trans_stock_movement 
        WHERE tanggal_movement='$datenow' 
        AND status_aktif='YES' AND kode_bahan_baku = '$kdbahan' ");
}
```

my view input text for **kode_bahan_baku** inside a post form

```
              <div class="form-group">                    
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bahan Baku</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama_bahan_baku" name="nama_bahan_baku" placeholder="Bahan Baku" value="" style="width:150px" required="required">
                        <input type="text" id="kode_bahan_baku" name="kode_bahan_baku" value="" class="form-control">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" id="btnMenu" data-target="#menuModal">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>                            
                    </div>
                </div>

               </div>
```

please help :(

Comment: why don't you try $this->input->post('kode_bahan_baku') ?

Comment: your $_POST is not working right ? so I gave you alternative to get the value you want

Comment: your form does have `method="POST"`, right? Is anything getting posted (try `var_dump($_POST);`)

Comment: @rahul_m oh wait, the error was gone. but it cant take any value from the textinput that i was filled

Comment: post your whole view code.

Comment: @Hekmat <input type="text"  id="kode_bahan_baku" name="kode_bahan_baku" value="5" class="form-control">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">

Comment: what is output of `echo $this->input->post('kode_bahan_baku')` on controller?

Comment: @Hekmat it must be "500" here's the database (screenshot): https://ibb.co/eMh7RF .

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is the go-between of your view and your model, as such, you should be grabbing the data out using `$this->input->post('kode_bahan_baku')` in the controller and passing those details through to the model:

Controller:

```
$kdbahan = $this->input->post('kode_bahan_baku');

$dbResultObj = $this->yourLoadedModel->sumqtyin($kdbahan);
```

then use the object `$dbResultObj` like: `$dbResultObj->qty_in` to get out the result

Model:

```
function sumqtyin($kdbahan){
$datenow = date("Y-m-d");

return $this->db->select('SUM(IFNULL(qty_in,0)) AS qty_in')
    ->where('tanggal_movement', $datenow)
    ->where('status_aktif', 'YES')
    ->where('kode_bahan_baku', $kdbahan)
    ->get('trans_stock_movement')
    ->result();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow the MVC structure , Before you make any manipulation on database you just have to follow the MVC method .

VIEW => CONTROLLER => MODEL => CONTROLLER => VIEW

like @Brian Ramsey did . check out the guidelines of codeigniter

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/